# How to enforce implementation of nested class properties?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I'm trying to implement my own multi-language feature in Blazor WASM. Nothing fancy but I would like to make sure I don't forget to implement properties in a specific language. In TypeScript this would work with typing or interfacing objects. In C# the equivalent of such an object would be a class. I tried using interfaces and abstract classes in C# but I'm not getting the desired result.

The desired result would be for my code editor to hint when I forgot to implement a property. How should I proceed?

I could just put all properties directly into the `Translation` class to enforce their implementation but than I'll have one very long list of properties, I'd prefer to chop them up a bit.

```
    public class NavMenuProps
    {
        public string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; } = "Dogs";
        public string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; } = "Facilities";
        public string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; } = "Profile";
    }
    
    public abstract class Translation
    {
        public abstract NavMenuProps NavMenu();
    }
    
    public class English : Translation
    {
        public override NavMenuProps NavMenu()
        {
            return new NavMenuProps();
        }
    }
        
    public class Dutch : Translation
    {
        public override NavMenuProps NavMenu()
        {
            return new NavMenuProps
            {
                FirstMenuHeader = "Honden",
                SecondMenuHeader = ""
            };
        }
    }

    public class French : Translation
    {
        public override NavMenuProps NavMenu()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In TypeScript it would work like this:

```
type TNavMenuProps = {
    firstMenuHeader: string;
    secondMenuHeader: string;
    thirdMenuHeader: string;
    ...
}

type TLoginPageProps = {
    firstLabel: string;
    secondLabel: string;
    ...
}

type TTranslation = {
    navMenu: TNavMenuProps;
    loginPage: TLoginPageProps;
    ...
}

const englishTranslations: TTranslation = {
    navMenu: {
        firstMenuHeader: "first";
        secondMenuHeader: "second";
        // Would complain I forgot "thirdMenuHeader".
    },
    loginPage: {
        firstLabel: "1st label";
        secondLabel: "2nd label";
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: How about giving `NavMenuProps` a constructor that takes the three strings as arguments?

Comment: "The desired result would be for my code editor to hint when I forgot to implement a property." Do you want this, but _also_ the ability to use the fallback values you have defined in `NavMenuProps`? (As is done with the `English` class in your example)

Comment: @pschill `NavMenuProps` will contain 10 or more props and I want to do similar things for whole pages, translate all the content on there.
@AstridE. It's not a requirement, I don't mind initializing the English one instead of defaulting.

Comment: So what was the problem with using interfaces?

Comment: @BentTranberg interfaces would tell me to implement the properties/methods of `Translation`  but not give a damn wether I initialized `NavMenuProps` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirements, here is the solution

Declare NavMenu properties as interface

```
public interface NavMenuProps
{
    public string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; }
}
```

Declare Translation class as abstract with abstract properties

```
public abstract class Translation : NavMenuProps
{
    public abstract string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public abstract string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public abstract string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can implemented each language translation, if you do not implement NavMenuProps properties in any language class, code editor will complain like "Does not implement inherited abstract member"

```
public class English : Translation
{
    public override string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public override string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public override string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; }
}

public class Dutch : Translation
{
    public override string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public override string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public override string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; }
}

public class French : Translation
{
    public override string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public override string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; }
    public override string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does what it needs to do. I was too fixated on not poluting the `Translation` class when inheriting from multiple interfaces but yours in a great solution. Actually I can achieve the same by turning `Transaction` into an interface and leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this could be a way to go: Make `NavMenuProps` `abstract`, and implement `NavMenu()` inside `Translation`. Now, rather than implementing `NavMenu()` in all of the classes that inherit `Translation`, you rather need to implement all properties in `NavMenuProps` in all those classes.

```
public abstract class NavMenuProps
{
    public abstract string FirstMenuHeader { get; }
    public abstract string SecondMenuHeader { get; }
    public abstract string ThirdMenuHeader { get; }
}

public abstract class Translation : NavMenuProps
{
    public Translation NavMenu() => this;
}

public class English : Translation
{
    public override string FirstMenuHeader => "First";
    public override string SecondMenuHeader => "Second";
    public override string ThirdMenuHeader => "Third";
}
```

Now you can call

```
var englishMenu = new English().NavMenu();
```

---

If there is any need to implement `NavMenu()` in any other way for some classes, you could make it `virtual` and override it where needed:

```
public abstract class Translation : NavMenuProps
{
    public virtual Translation NavMenu() => this;
}

public class English : Translation
{
    //...

    public override Translation NavMenu()
    {
        //return base.NavMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! It's not exactly what I need. In the first codeblock I might as well just paste all the properties for all translation strings throughout the app. The last codeblock results in the same as my original post, not enforcing me to override all the `NavMenuProps`, if I understand your code correctly.
I want my IDE to tell me: "You forgot to override `ThirdMenuHeader`".

Comment: @AugusteVN I am not quite sure what you mean with "In the first codeblock I might as well just paste all the properties for all translation strings throughout the app."? The last codeblock was just an example; I didn't really expect an override of `NavMenu()` to be needed at all, but thought I'd inform how it could be achieved.

Comment: @AugusteVN Did you try this code at all? Perhaps depending on your IDE, but I get a red, squiggly line under `English` if I leave out the implementation of either of the `*MenuHeader` properties: _'English' does not implement inherited abstract member 'NavMenuProps.*MenuHeader.get'_. (I'm using Visual Studio 2022 - Enterprise)

Comment: `Translation` can't inherit from `NavMenuProps` as I want to do this for multiple classes containing string properties.

Comment: I tried the code, similar result as just using one interface or abstract class.

Comment: @AugusteVN Ah, okay. I didn't understand from your original question that that was your scenario. But knowing that, I agree that this will not work for you. Perhaps include that information in your original post, with code examples of another class?

Comment: I added a TypeScript sample to illustrate my intentions better.

Comment: @AugusteVN Great :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Answer posted on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer section)*.

The solution is not that much better than having just one giant interface but it does what I need, which is having manageable interfaces and the IDE telling me when I forgot to implement a field.

Solution inspired by the accepted answer:

```
    public interface INavMenuProps
    {
        public string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; }
        public string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; }
        public string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ILoginPageProps
    {
        public string FirstLabel { get; set; }
        public string SecondLabel { get; set; }
    }
    
    public interface Translation : INavMenuProps, ILoginPageProps
    {
    }
    
    public class English : Translation
    {
        public string FirstMenuHeader { get; set; } = "Dogs";
        public string SecondMenuHeader { get; set; } = "Facilities";
        public string ThirdMenuHeader { get; set; } = "Profile";

        public string FirstLabel { get; set; } = "1st label";
        public string SecondLabel { get; set; } = "2nd label";
    }
        
    public class Dutch : Translation
    {
        
    }

    public class French : Translation
    {
        
    }
```